# Easy (probably) equation for video game. Precentages

Tags: calculus, probability

I'm coding silly things for silly video games.

I need a formula that will calculate the precentages based on a number of factors:

- If I have 3 seconds of Attack Speed, and my character has an Agility
  rating of 0 and a Speed rating of 0, my AttackSpeed remains at 3
  seconds.
- if I have an Attack Speed of 3 seconds and my character has an
  Agility rating of 10 and a Speed Rating of 10, my Attack Speed should
  now be 50% faster.
- The Agility rating should affect the Attack speed 2 times more than
  the Speed rating if possible.

If someone would be so kind and write out this formula for me so I can implement it in my code.

I would also appreciate a little explanation or something to help me understand and learn. I will need to implement this formula again, sometimes based on more than 2 factors.

Comment: There's a bit of ambiguity when you say "50%" faster. Does it mean delay between attacks is reduced by 50% (so it takes 1.5 secs for each attack), or does it mean you do 1.5 times more  attacks per second compared to before? Also, do you want to make it so that speed rating and agility rating stack multiplicatively or additively?

Comment: The value "AttackSpeed" is being used as a delay to stop the player from executing code that would trigger an attack. I convert the number from "AttackSpeed" to seconds and start subtracting, when it reaches 0 or below the player is able to trigger the attack function again. Think of it as a fire rate for example.

Comment: Also, do you want to make it so that speed rating and agility rating stack multiplicatively or additively? I'm afraid I don't know what that means.

Comment: Yes, but there are still two different interpretations for "increase in attack speed by 50%". If it decreases the delay by 50%, then player is able to attack every 1.5 seconds. This means you can attack twice as fast. However, if it increases the number of attacks per second by 1.5 times, you only attack 1.5 times faster. Which one do you want?

Comment: Come to think of it, I'll eventually need both versions, for projectile based attacks it functions as a firerate and will be responsible for the delay between attacks. For melee based attacks it will directly control the speed at which an attack animation is played and speed that up respectively.

Comment: Right, but still there are many possible implementations of your criteria. Suppose your agility rating is $r_a$ and speed rating is $r_s$. Let $AS$ be attack speed. One implementation is $\displaystyle AS=3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{\frac{2r_a}{30} + \frac{r_s}{30}}$. Another one: $AS=3(1-0.5(31-2r_a-r_s))$. I think first one might be reasonable, why second one is rather silly, but both of them fits your criteria

Comment: Ok now I'm lost completely. I guess I should mention I sadly fail at 4th grade math. The best way I can put it is: The value of AttackSpeed (which is 3) needs to end up as 1.5 if Agility and Speed are both 10. Its possible I underestimated this quite a bit, generally I need a formula written out with the basic signs (+, -, *, /) The code is written in C# and I'm somewhat of a beginner, I need it as plain as possible.